# Stack without use of STL - Version 1.1

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack

I had already posted this question at [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75223/stack-code-without-use-of-stl)
and have tried to incorporate some of the suggestions given. Kindly let me know if there are still some concerns/suggestions/improvements in the code mentioned below.

```
#include"iostream"
#define MAX_SIZE 5
class Mystack
{
private:
    int A[MAX_SIZE];
    int top;
public:
    Mystack();
    void push(int x);
    int pop();
    int topElement();
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
    void print();
};
    Mystack::Mystack()
    {
        top = -1;
    }
    void Mystack::push(int x)
    {
        if(isFull())
        {
            std::cout << "Stack Overflow" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            top++;
            A[top] = x;
        }
    }
    bool Mystack::isFull()
    {
        if (top == MAX_SIZE - 1)
        {
            std::cout << "Stack is full"<< std::endl;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Stack is not full"<<std::endl;
            return false;
        }

    }
    int Mystack::pop()
    {
        if (isEmpty())
        {
            std::cout << "Stack Underflow" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "The popped element is" << A[top];
            return A[top--];
        }
    }
    bool Mystack::isEmpty()
    {
        if (top == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Stack is empty" << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Stack is not empty" << std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
    int Mystack::topElement()
    {
        std::cout<<"The top element is : "<< A[top];
        return A[top];
    }
    void Mystack::print()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <=top; i++)
        {
            std::cout  << A[i]<< " ";
        }
    }
void main()
{
    Mystack s1;
    int num,choice = 1;
    while (choice >0)
    {
        std::cout << "\n1. PUSH"<< std::endl;
        std::cout << "2. TOP" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "3. IsEmpty" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "4. POP" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "5. EXIT" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "6. Print" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "7. IsFull" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter the choice" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "Enter the number to be pushed" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> num;
            s1.push(num);
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Get the TOP Element" << std::endl;
            s1.topElement();
            break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Check Empty" << std::endl;
            s1.isEmpty();
            break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "POP the element" << std::endl;
            s1.pop();
            break;
        case 5: exit(0);
        case 6:
            s1.print();
            break;
        case 7: 
            s1.isFull();
            break;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't mix a "library" class and input/output that is a bad style. If you really need to output some debug output, use a logger.
2. In `push()`, in case the a stack is full, you need to throw an exception or return an error code. Don't just silently ignore the error.
3. Same problem with the `pop()` method. Don't just ignore the error, notify the caller. And do not simply return 0, because it is a valid value that can be stored in a stack, so caller will not be able to distinguish error from successful call.
4. `isFull()` can be rewritten as a one-liner:

   ```
   isFull() { return top == MAX_SIZE - 1; }
   ```
5. Don't use `#define` to define a constant. Use `const int`. `#define` works as a simple text substitution and is a very old and very outdated way to define constants.
6. Add templates to your stack to support not only a stack of `int`s, but a stack of any type.
7. Is it a feature that your stack has a limited size? If yes, consider specifying max size through the constructor. If not, extend your internal array when the limit is reached.
8. The `top` variable is pointing to the last set element. Why not to change invariant to "point to the first free element" and replace this awkward `top = -1` initialization with `top = 0`?
9. `print()` should not be in your stack class. Provide a generic way to iterate though your stack (read about how STL iterators are implemented or implement your own iterator) and let a user decide what to do with each value from a stack while iterating it.
10. You can replace `top++; A[top] = x;` with `A[++top] = x`. You are using similar style in other place of your class anyway.
11. Consider renaming array `A`. The name is not descriptive at all.
12. Well... "Mystack" name is awkward, rename it to "Stack" :)