# Stack implementation using vectors and templates with no overflow version 1.3

Tags: c++, algorithm, stack

Below is the code for stack along with one or two extra options. Kindly let me know if there are any concerns/critical issues. Below are the links for previous versions.

[Version 1.0](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75235/stack-implementation-using-vectors-with-no-overflow-version-1-0/)

[Version 1.1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75352/stack-implementation-using-vectors-and-templates-with-no-overflow-version-1-1)

[Version 1.2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75835/stack-implementation-using-vectors-and-templates-with-no-overflow-version-1-2/)

```
 //*************Version 1.3: Begineer's Implementation of Stack ***************//

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

template <class T>
class Mystack
{

private:
    T *input;
    int top;
    int capacity;

public:
    Mystack();                                                                      
    Mystack(const Mystack<T> &source);                                              
    Mystack<T> & operator=(Mystack<T> source);                                      
    ~Mystack();                                                                     
    void push(T const& x);                                                          
    void pop();                                                                                                 
    T& topElement() const;                                                           
    bool isEmpty() const;                                                           
    void print(std::ostream &os) const;                                            
    void swap(Mystack<T> &source);                                                  
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d)   //operator<< overloading
    {
        d.print(s);
        return s;
    }
};

template <class T>
Mystack<T>::Mystack()                                     //default constructor  
{
    top = -1;
    capacity = 5;
    input = new T[capacity];
}

template <class T>
Mystack<T>::Mystack(const Mystack<T> &source)            //copy constructor
{
    input = new T[source.capacity];
    top = source.top;
    capacity = source.capacity;
    for (int i = 0; i <= source.top; i++)
    {
        input[i] = source.input[i];
    }
}

/**COPY AND SWAP IDIOM**/
template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::swap(Mystack<T>& source)                //swaps the content of 'source' to the object that calls it
{
    std::swap(input, source.input);
    std::swap(top, source.top);
    std::swap(capacity, source.capacity);
}

template <class T>
Mystack<T> & Mystack<T>::operator=(Mystack<T> source)     // assignment operator overload 
{                                            //^^^^^ passing by value hence copy constructor gets invoked, 
                                                    // thus no headache of copying, no code duplication, exception safe
    this->swap(source);
    return *this;                                   //temporary holder 'source' will get destroyed, 'source' scope ends and its destructor is called,
}                                                   //avoiding memory leak                                  


template <class T>
Mystack<T>::~Mystack()                           // destructor
{
    delete[] input;
}

template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::push(T const& x)               //Passing x by Const Reference 
{                                               // Valus of x cannot be changed now in the function!
    if (top + 1 == capacity)
    {
        T *vec = new T[capacity * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        {
            vec[i] = std::move(input[i]);
        }                           
        std::swap(input, vec);
        capacity *= 2;
        delete [] vec;               // Avoiding Memory Leak.
    }
    input[++top] = x;
}

template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::pop()                         //pop the element from the top of stack
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Stack Underflow");
    }
    /*else
    {
        std::cout << "The popped element is" << input[top--];
    }*/
    top--;
}

template <class T>
bool Mystack<T>::isEmpty() const                    //const: none of the class members can be modified in this function 
{
    return top == -1;
}

template <class T>
T& Mystack<T>::topElement() const                      // returns top element of the stack
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("No Element to Display");
    }
    else
    {
        //std::cout << "The top element is : " << input[top];
        return input[top];
    }
}

template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::print(std::ostream &os) const         //a more of a general print function, can be used to write to a file 
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
    {
        os << input[i] << " ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Mystack<int> intstack, inttemp;
    Mystack<float> floatstack, floattemp;
    Mystack <int> temp(intstack);
    Mystack<char> charstack, chartemp;
    int type_choice;
    std::ofstream some_file("testfile.txt");     // creation of file 
    int int_elem;
    float float_elem;
    char char_elem;
    int ch = 1;
    std::cout << "Enter the type of stack" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. int ";
    std::cout << "2. float ";
    std::cout << "3. Char" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> type_choice;

    std::cout << "\n1. Push ";
    std::cout << "2. Top ";
    std::cout << "3. IsEmpty ";
    std::cout << "4. Pop ";
    std::cout << "5. Write Data to a file";
    std::cout << "6. Copy Constrcutor Use";
    std::cout << "7. Assignemnt Operator Use";
    std::cout << "8. Print ";
    std::cout << "9. Exit" << std::endl;

    if (type_choice == 1)
    {
        int  ch = 1;    
        while (ch > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the choice" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> ch;
            switch (ch)
            {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Number to be pushed" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> int_elem;
                intstack.push(int_elem);
                break;
            case 2:
                try
                {
                    std::cout << "Top Element is: " << intstack.topElement();
                }
                catch (std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error:" << oor.what() << std::endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Check Empty" << std::endl;
                if (intstack.isEmpty())
                    std::cout << "Stack is Empty";
                else
                    std::cout << "Stack is not Empty";
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "Pop the element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    intstack.pop();
                }
                catch (const std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                std::cout << "Stack data to file" << std::endl;
                intstack.print(some_file);                          //printing data to a file
                break;
            case 6:
            {
                Mystack<int> s4(intstack);                       // copy constructor called
                s4.print(std::cout);
                break;
            }
            case 7:
                inttemp = intstack;                             // assignment operator overload
                inttemp.print(std::cout);
                break;
            case 8:
                std::cout << intstack;                              // << operator overloading
                break;
            case 9:
                exit(0);
            default:
                std::cout << "Enter a valid input" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (type_choice == 2)
    {
        int  ch = 1;
        while (ch > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the choice" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> ch;
            switch (ch)
            {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Number to be pushed" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> float_elem;
                floatstack.push(float_elem);
                break;
            case 2:
                try
                {
                    std::cout << "Top Element" << floatstack.topElement();
                }
                catch (std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error:" << oor.what() << std::endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Check Empty" << std::endl;
                if (floatstack.isEmpty())
                    std::cout << "Stack is Empty";
                else
                    std::cout << "Stack is not Empty";
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "Pop the element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    floatstack.pop();
                }
                catch (const std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                std::cout << "Stack data to file" << std::endl;
                floatstack.print(some_file);                                //data to file
                break;
            case 6:
            {
                Mystack<float> s5 = floatstack;                            // copy constructor called
                s5.print(std::cout);
                break;
            }
            case 7:
                floattemp = floatstack;                                     // assignment operator overload
                floattemp.print(std::cout);
                break;
            case 8:
                std::cout << floatstack;                                    //operator << overloading 
                break;
            case 9:
                exit(0);
            default:
                std::cout << "Enter a valid input" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (type_choice == 3)
    {
        int  ch = 1;
        while (ch > 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter the choice" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> ch;
            switch (ch)
            {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Number to be pushed" << std::endl;
                std::cin >> char_elem;
                charstack.push(char_elem);
                break;
            case 2:
                try
                {
                    std::cout << "Top Element" << charstack.topElement();
                }
                catch (std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error:" << oor.what() << std::endl;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                std::cout << "Check Empty" << std::endl;
                if (charstack.isEmpty())
                    std::cout << "Stack is Empty";
                else
                    std::cout << "Stack is not Empty";
                break;
            case 4:
                std::cout << "Pop the element" << std::endl;
                try
                {
                    charstack.pop();
                }
                catch (const std::out_of_range &oor)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Out of Range error: " << oor.what() << '\n';
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                std::cout << "Stack data to file" << std::endl;                        
                charstack.print(some_file);                                 //printing stack data to file
                break;
            case 6:
            {
                Mystack<char> s6 = charstack;                               // copy constructor called
                s6.print(std::cout);
                break;
            }
            case 7:
                chartemp = charstack;
                chartemp.print(std::cout);
                break;
            case 8:
                std::cout << charstack;                                      //operator << overloading
                break;
            case 9:
                exit(0);
            default:
                std::cout << "Enter a valid input" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Invalid Choice";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't like this comment:

```
{     // Valus of x cannot be changed now in the function!
```

I think that is obvious.
But you are not manipulating `x` in the function so not a problem and you make a copy when you put it on the stack.

Don't like the usless else

```
else
{
    //std::cout << "The popped element is" << input[top];
    --top;
}
```

The true part of the branch never returns. So the else is redundant. I like to keep validation logic (test that the pre-conditions are met) separate from the business logic of the class.

Apart from that I can not spot anything wrong.

Couple of additions (I mention in the first review).

- Using placement new/delete so that you don't construct objects that are not needed.
- You could add move semantics to the class

  - Constructor
  - assignment
  - push.

Answer (score 2):

in your push you allocate the storage with `new T[]` so you should delete with `delete[]`

```
template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::push(T const& x)               //Passing x by Const Reference 
{                                               // Valus of x cannot be changed now in the function!
    if (top + 1 == capacity)
    {
        T *vec = new T[capacity * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
        {
            vec[i] = std::move(input[i]);
        }                           
        std::swap(input, vec);
        capacity *= 2;
        delete[] vec;               // Avoiding Memory Leak.
    }
    input[++top] = x;
}
```

consider also adding a moveable push that you can call with `vector.push(std::move(foo));`

Your `pop` doesn't, looks like a typo during debugging:

```
template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::pop()                         //pop the element from the top of stack
{
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        throw std::out_of_range("Stack Underflow");
    }
    else
    {
        //std::cout << "The popped element is" << input[top];
        --top;
    }
}
```

Besides that because you allocate with `new T[]` the default constructor will be called for each element each time you allocate and the destructor each time you `delete[]`. To avoid that you can use placement new and placement delete instead. This requires you to loop over all elements that you initialized and call the destructor on it during deallocation. Though this is more complicated to keep track of; the `std` containers outsource this to an allocator object.

Answer (score 0):

There is two notes I have regarding your code: Use `unsigned` more and the use of `-1` in the index variable - it screams "invalid offset" to me, even though I know you check for it.

You current semantics of `top` is "-1 means empty, otherwise it is the index of top element". If you change it to "index of the next element to be added", `0` will have the meaning of empty stack, allowing you to use `unsigned` type for `top`.